# Filter excel column and iterate (only) filtered rows using Apache Poi (HSSFSheet)

Tags: java, excel, parsing, apache-poi, xls

i would like to filter a column in an excel sheet
Once filtered, iterate over the filtered rows only

i tried using method {setAutoFilter} and was able to add a filter to the column but the return value of that method did not provide me with the filtered rows which is what i was looking for

i read that there are custom filters but from what i see they apply only to XSSFSheet and not to HSSFSheet 
also this uses some kind of XML representation.

is there anyway to do this? even using a different approach

i am using Apache Poi HSSFWorkbook & HSSFSheet to parse my .xls file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Iterate over all rows, and check the filter condition yourself before processing / ignoring?

Comment: thanks @Gagravarr , what do you mean check the filter condition?
do you mean to ignore the Autofilter/Customfilter feature and implement it myself? i.e. iterate over all rows and for each row check if the cell value is the filter value?
if YES- this seems very tedious and i would assume there is something implemented that does this already,
Again- Thanks